# PHP: Polish UTF-8 characters displayed incorrectly

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

First of all, hello everyone. I have an issue with PHP and Polish characters, namely "ą Ą ć Ć ę Ę ł Ł ń Ń ó Ó ś Ś ź Ź ż Ż". Below is my example code. I have all the Polish signs in `$string` variable and their correspondent UTF-8 (hex) represnetation in `$utfString` variable.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$string = 'ą Ą ć Ć ę Ę ł Ł ń Ń ó Ó ś Ś ź Ź ż Ż';
$utfString = "\xC4\x85 \xC4\x84 \xC4\x87 \xC4\x86 ".
    "\xC4\x99 \xC4\x98 \xC5\x82 \xC5\x81 ".
    "\xC5\x84 \xC5\x83 \xC3\xB3 \xC3\x93 ".
    "\xC5\x9B \xC5\x9A \xC5\xBA \xC5\xB9 ".
    "\xC5\xBC \xC5\xBB";

echo $string;
var_dump(utf8_encode($string));
echo $utfString;
var_dump(utf8_encode($utfString));

?>
```

The response from the browser presents as here:

```
� � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � �
string '¹ ¥ æ Æ ê Ê ³ £ ñ Ñ ó Ó     ¿ ¯' (length=53)
ą Ą ć Ć ę Ę ł Ł ń Ń ó Ó ś Ś ź Ź ż Ż
string 'Ä Ä Ä Ä Ä Ä Å Å Å Å Ã³ Ã Å Å Åº Å¹ Å¼ Å»' (length=89)
```

As you can see outputs are different for those strings. My question is what can I do about it? I was thinking of writing a function that would convert Polish signs in code into their respective UTF-8 representation but that seems far from optimal and rather difficult. Another option would be just to use this UTF-8 representation whenever i would need a Polish sign, but then again, I don't believe it should be this hard and convoluted. What's interesting, when I fetch such a string from database and display it, everything works correctly.

Script file is encoded as UTF-8 without BOM.

Answer (score 0):

`utf8_encode` is a poorly named function which is very rarely what you need. It converts text encoded in ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8, so if your text is not in that specific encoding to begin with, it will not help you.

PHP does not have any built-in notion of character encoding, Unicode or otherwise; a string is just a set of bytes, and `echo` just sends those bytes to the output (and thus, generally, to the browser). You don't need to tell PHP that a string you're outputting is UTF-8, because it doesn't care.

In your case, I think the answer is simply not to call `utf8_encode`.

Comment: That is not the problem. I know that `utf8_encode()` does not do the job. I used `utf8_encode()` only inside `var_dump()` in order to see any content of the variable `$string`. Otherwise it just shows questionmarks. The main problem is that `echo` with "normal" strings gives wrong results. For example if I would like to display word "błąd" I would have to use something like `'b'."\xC5\x82\xC4\x85".'d'` instead of `błąd`.

Comment: You're still treating utf8_encode as some magic "make my string visible" function. That is not what it does. All you're doing is making it harder to discover the real problem. What you need to know is what bytes are being output (without processing them in any way), e.g. using a hex editor or the `ord()` function.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. Apparently scrypt file wasn't encoded as UTF-8 without BOM in spite of demanding it on save file. The hint with using the hex editor made me realize that, so thank you for the help. I can't mark your answer as a correct one, since that was not the problem, but still thank you.